# How to use for loop method in R to generate a table with information from both rows and columns

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

This is just a snapshot of my dataset. I have 12 org corresponding to 23 different abx.classes (e.g. penicillin, aminoglycosides, and etc.). i have to generate a table with 4 columns; org, abx class, total number of 0 (refers to resistant), total number of 1 (refers to susceptible). i need to do this using the loop method for it to me automatic(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHjNM.png) and not keyed in manually. pairs of org and abx.class with values either 0 or 1 should form.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCq5V.png)

```
df_long <- pivot_longer(filtered_mergedfinal, cols = c(Penicillins, Aminoglycosides,    Trimethoprim,   Macrolides, Lincosamides,   Second_gen_cephalosporins,  
                                      Third_gen_cephalosporins, Fluoroquinolones,   Carbapenems,    Glycylcyclines, Fourth_gen_cephalosporins,  
                                      Polymyxins,   Beta_lactam_beta_lactamase_inhibitor,   Monobactams,    Amphenicols, Trimethoprim_sulfonamide,
                                      Tetracyclines,    Beta_lactam,
                                      Glycopeptides,    Oxazolidinones, First_gen_cephalosporins,   Sulfonaminde,   Steroid),
                        names_to = "abx.class", values_to = "suscept")
result2 <- df_long %>% group_by (org, abx.class, suscept) %>% summarise(frequency=n())

lancet <- na.omit(result2)

filtered_lancet <- lancet %>% filter(!grepl("other|contaminant", org))

library(tidyr)

# Pivot the data wider
transformed_lancet <- lancet %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "suscept", values_from = "frequency", names_prefix = "suscept_")

susceptdata <- na.omit(transformed_lancet)
```

Error:
i did this but i need to use the loop method as this is forcing the data to look in the way i want it. instead of making use the dataframe with all parameters to work for me (extracting the desired information).

Comment: A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) would help us to help you.

Comment: Which part of your code do want to make automatic? By the way, you don't have to list every single column name in your `pivot_longer` call. Just omit the `org` column like this: `cols=!org` or you could also specify the first and the last columns of interest: `cols=c(Penicillins:Steroid)`

Comment: Do you happen to know how i can do via the loop method. Automatic as in if one day, the dataset is updated, we shouldn't need to mention the specific rows or column

Comment: I think there is a problem with your code: it only outputs bigger than 0 counts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a random sample to model your data:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- cbind(org = sample(c("A","B", "C"), 10, T), as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1, NA), 100, T), 10)))

> arrange(df1, org)
   org V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1    A NA NA  1  1 NA  0  0  0  1   1
2    A  0  0 NA NA  1 NA  0  0  1   0
3    A  1  0 NA  0  1 NA  1  1  1  NA
4    B  0  0  0  1  1  1 NA NA NA  NA
5    B  1  0  1  1  1 NA  0 NA NA   1
6    B NA  1  1  1  1 NA  1 NA NA   0
7    C  0  0  0  0  1 NA  0  0  1   1
8    C  1  1  1  0  0 NA NA  0  1   1
9    C  1  0  1 NA  1  1  0  0 NA  NA
10   C  0  1 NA NA  1  0  0 NA  0   1
```

... and below is the loop, to output the counts

```
result <- data.frame() # empty dataframe    
for (i in 2:ncol(df1)){
  loop_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
          tapply(df1[,i], df1$org, \(x)
                 c(names(df1)[i], sum(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                   sum(x==0, na.rm = TRUE)
                       ))))
  loop_df$org <- rownames(loop_df)
  rownames(loop_df) <- NULL
  result <- rbind(result, loop_df)      
}

names(result)<- c("abx.class", "suscept_1", "suscept_0", "org")
```

The result is:

```
> result|>select(org, everything())
   org abx.class suscept_1 suscept_0
1    A        V1         1         1
2    B        V1         1         1
3    C        V1         2         2
4    A        V2         0         2
5    B        V2         1         2
6    C        V2         2         2
7    A        V3         1         0
8    B        V3         2         1
9    C        V3         2         1
10   A        V4         1         1
11   B        V4         3         0
12   C        V4         0         2
13   A        V5         2         0
14   B        V5         3         0
15   C        V5         3         1
16   A        V6         0         1
17   B        V6         1         0
18   C        V6         1         1
19   A        V7         1         2
20   B        V7         1         1
21   C        V7         0         3
22   A        V8         1         2
23   B        V8         0         0
24   C        V8         0         3
25   A        V9         3         0
26   B        V9         0         0
27   C        V9         2         1
28   A       V10         1         1
29   B       V10         1         1
30   C       V10         3         0
```

Comment: Now I want to calculate propensity scores (PS) for which I need to build a logistic regression first. 
2 dataframes of interest: 
Dataframe 1: abxsusfinal
4 Columns: Antibiotic class, organism, number of 0 and 1 (dataframe we just formed following the steps above)
Dataframe 2: filtered_mergedfinal
Covariates data + abx class and org combination (as shown in the figure in previous question). question continued in next comments due to word limit

Comment: For e.g. aminoglycosides (abx class) and acito (org) has 108 patient data, similarly with other combinations we would have so much data too. So how can we, via a looping method, calculate PS for each combination with their relevant data from both the dataframes?

Comment: @atharvi gupta you should put it as a separate question in order to fully explain the desired outcome. But this time, instead of the screenshots, make your dataset available for copying via `dput(df)` (reduce it if it's too big).